# How to sparate app files from test files in a Yeoman Fountain project?

Tags: reactjs, yeoman, karma-jasmine, ecmascript-5

Using a [Fountain](http://fountainjs.io/) webapp generator and creating a TODO example app with React + Webpack + ES5 + Gulp, and getting the sources:

How to configure Karma and/or Gulp and/or Webpack to separate the app source files and the test source files?
( How to separate the `*.js` from the `*.spec.js`? )

[image: List of source files]